# Creating subgraphs with torch_geometric.loader.NeighborLoader while preserving all edges

Tags: pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I have a graph with node and edge features and I want to perform node classification using attention on both nodes and edges. Since my graph is large, I need to create mini-batches. I would like to use torch_geometric.loader.NeighborLoader to create subgraphs that are not randomly sampled. However, with this class, not all edges are preserved and I lose information. Based on the documentation, I thought passing disjoint=True and directed=False would give me what I want, but I get a RuntimeError: Undirected subgraphs not yet supported. I am using PyTorch 2.0.1 and torch_geometric 2.3.0.

I was using torch 1.13 and I switched to 2.0 but it didn't change anything. I also tried the latest version of torch_geometric but also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The directed=False is what that's causing your problem. Consider setting it up to True, since the directed attribute doesn't mean that your graph is directed.

The information loss will always happen, since the graph data isn't i.i.d anyway.

One more thing to note is that NeighborLoader is not deterministic since the torch.scatter operation (on which is the NeighborLoader based) on the GPUs has randomness to it. See issue #95 on PyG.